# What exactly is Jayne doing here?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), the Reavers and Alliance battle while Wash pilots the transport spaceship Serenity through the crossfire. In the ship, Malcolm commands his crew to strap themselves in:

> Wash: We're fried. I got no control.
>
> Malcolm: Where's the backup? Where's the backup?

Then, Jayne goes to the crew who strapped themselves in:

> Jayne: **Check! Check!**

[image: Jayne scrambles on hands and knees through the main room as the caption reads "glass shattering." He jumps up and stumbles into a room where Kaylee and Inara are in seats, throwing a table out of the way as he goes. The caption reads "Explosions." He goes to Kaylee and Inara in turn calling "Check" for each of them. The scene cuts to Serenity freefalling out of the sky with the caption "Engine whining."]

Suddenly scene changes to Serenity in free fall.

What exactly is Jayne doing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [original script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Serenity.html), Jayne's assigned duty in the event of a crash seems to be to ensure that other crew members are strapped in properly. Each time he says 'check', he's performed a check.

> INT. BRIDGE - CONTINUING
>
> Wash is fighting the stick with extreme concentration as Zoe pulls out a seat as well, straps in.
>
> INT. AFT HALL - CONTINUING
>
> **Jayne, Simon and Inara pull harnesses not unlike "Batman the Ride" seats from the ceiling, help the others in.**

We also see him throwing moveable objects, like the table, away from the safety chairs.